# How to explode inner arrays in a struct inside a struct in pyspark/

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to spark. I have tried exploding a `array` inside of a `struct`. The JSON loop is a bit complex as below.

```
{
"id": 1,
"firstfield": "abc",
"secondfield": "zxc",
"firststruct": {
    "secondstruct": {
        "firstarray": [{
            "firstarrayfirstfield": "asd",
            "firstarraysecondfield": "dasd",
            "secondarray": [{
                "score": " 7 "
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to get access to `score` field under `secondarray` field to be able to calculate few metrics and come up with the average score of each `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Glue then you should convert DynamicFrame into Spark's DataFrame and then use [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

scoresDf = dynamicFrame.toDF
  .withColumn("firstExplode", explode(col("firststruct.secondstruct.firstarray")))
  .withColumn("secondExplode", explode(col("firstExplode.secondarray")))
  .select("secondExplode.score") 

scoresDyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(scoresDf, glueContext, "scoresDyf")
```

Comment: 18/09/27 13:43:20 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/09/27 13:43:20 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/09/27 13:43:20 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
End of LogType:stderr

Comment: This is what the script returns in logs and dosent print the schema

Comment: The code I provided doesn't print schema. If you want you can add `scoresDf.printSchema()`. Logs look ok

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have done this scoresDf.printSchema() which dosent print schema

Comment: Does it print anything if remove `.select("secondExplode.score")`?